# EF Core 3.0 providing inconsistent results between client and server side date comparisons

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.0

When comparing against the DateTimeOffset.Date property, we're seeing inconsistent results on client side vs server side evaluation.

Given the entity:

```cs
public partial class PreHire
{
    public int PreHireId { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

And the following logic:

```cs
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;

//Pulls preHire with a start date of '2019-11-25 14:42:54.0833333 +00:00'
PreHire clientComparePreHire = context.PreHire.Where(x => x.PreHireId == 22407).FirstOrDefault();
if(clientComparePreHire.StartDate.Date >= startDate.Date)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This works.");
}

List<PreHire> serverComparePreHires = context.PreHire.Where(q => q.StartDate.Date >= startDate.Date).ToList();
if(serverComparePreHires.Count == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This doesn't. This shouldn't be empty.");
}
```

We get the following logs:

```sql
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20100]
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT TOP(1) [p].[PreHireID], [p].[StartDate]
      FROM [TBL].[PreHire] AS [p]
      WHERE [p].[PreHireID] = 22407
This works.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20100]
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@__startDate_Date_0='2019-11-25T00:00:00' (DbType = DateTimeOffset)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [p].[PreHireID], [p].[StartDate]
      FROM [TBL].[PreHire] AS [p]
      WHERE CONVERT(date, [p].[StartDate]) >= @__startDate_Date_0
This doesn't. This shouldn't be empty.
```

This shows that serverComparePreHires is empty, but if I run the above query manually I get my expected result:

```sql
SELECT [p].[PreHireID], [p].[StartDate]
FROM [TBL].[PreHire] AS [p]
WHERE CONVERT(date, [p].[StartDate]) >= '2019-11-25T00:00:00'

PreHireID   StartDate
22407   2019-11-25 14:42:54.0833333 +00:00
```

To summarize, When processing this specific linq query server side, EF Core generates a valid SQL Query but fails to return the matching `PreHire` entry. Is there something I'm missing here? From my research, EF Core should be capable of processing any `DateTime.Date` queries.

---

> Other details

- EF Core version: 3.0.0 (Same result with 3.0.1)
- Database provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- Target framework: .NET Core 3.0 (Migrating from 2.1)
- Operating system: Windows 10
- IDE: Visual Studio 2019 16.3.7